# Read specific files with Spark (exact match only)

Tags: python, apache-spark

I need to read a specific set of text files using Spark:

```py
df = spark.text.read(paths)
```

The problem is that Spark treats the path as either a directory or a file. This has two problems:

1. If the file does not exist, it's skipped with just a warning in the log – "directory does not exist; was it deleted recently?"
2. Trying to list the path as a directory takes additional processing time.

From the documentation, Spark uses partition discovery by default (which means it must try to list the path as a directory), but it can also operate in a different mode – enabled by the `recursiveFileLookup` option.

What I want is a third mode where it just reads each of the provided paths as an exact match file. Is there a way to achieve this without a change in Spark's read method?

Comment: `sc.textFile(...)` doesn't work for you? https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile

Comment: @mazaneicha `sc.wholeTextFiles(",".join(paths))` does the trick – I believe it's equivalent to `sc.textFile(...)`. Thanks!